# Which is best for a 4e Hexblade, wands or rods?

Tags: dnd-4e, implements

I'm running a fey Hexblade in a 4e game and have been thinking of taking the Wand or Rod expertise feat. Since Rods tend to rely on cursing powers I don't have, and wands seem to rely on wizards spells as far as I've seen, I'm not sure which benefits me more. Which would be the best choice?

Alternatively, what are some good wands or rods that might work well with fire, lightening, or, particularly, cold, powers? If there's a "killer app" wand or rod, that might make the choice easy.

Answer (score 1):

The only implement I saw for rods &/or wands that improved cold attacks is the "Wand of Cold" (AV1).

```
Implement (Wand)
Enhancement: Attack rolls and damage rolls
Critical: +1d8 cold damage per plus
Property: Gain a +1 item bonus to damage rolls when you use this wand to attack with a power that has the cold and implement keywords.
Level 13 or 18: +2 item bonus
Level 23 or 28: +3 item bonus
Power (Encounter: Arcane, Cold, Implement): Standard Action. As the wizard's ray of frost power (PH 159).
```

As such I would recommend wand expertise as you advised that you wouldn't be using curses.

(Sorry playing with formatting for the first time so bear with me.)